# What percentage of the keyspace should be brute-forced to find an equivalent key if the block cipher has?

Tags: block-cipher, keys

I have been reading the [Hasty Pudding Cipher specification](https://web.archive.org/web/20080724003621if_/http://www.cs.arizona.edu/%7Ercs/hpc/hpc-ov-cl-hl-sp) and the author make clear that the cipher has some equivalent keys if the keyspace is larger than 8192-bits:

```
Two keys are equivalent if they expand to the same key-expansion
table.  The likelihood is negligible for keys of size < 1/2 the
key-expansion table size, 8192 bits.  For keys longer than this, some
will be equivalent, but there is no feasible way to discover an
equivalent key pair.
```

My question is? What percentage of keyspace of an block cipher should be brute-forced to find an equivalent key (if the cipher has equivalent keys)?

Comment: `but there is no feasible way to discover an equivalent key pair.`. Are you asking for an answer for this?

Comment: @kelalaka Yes. It's valid.

Comment: Is it looked at an answer independent of the block cipher (with equivalent keys), considered as a black box; or is the question geared only at HPC? In the second case, what restriction (if any) does "brute-forced" imply? Does the question boil down to: what would be the effort to discover an equivalent key pair for HPC?